# Date Showing up as "1969-12-31" in DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to store a date value in a MySQL database using `serialize()`. However, the result in the db is treated as "1969-12-31". I'm almost certain it's because of the way the data is being serialized in my ajax call.

Here are the code snippets. Where am I going wrong?

Ajax portion:

```
data: decodeURIComponent(form.serialize()),
```

The Result portion of the serialized data is this (when I view the serialized data in console):

```
&pur-date=2014+/+02+/+31
```

^ I think the "+" is what's causing the error.

In my model (Codeigniter):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post('pur-date')));
```

If I replace the `strtotime` value to "2014-10-10" for example, the data is correctly stored into the db. So the issue has to be related to the post data coming in.

Note, column type in db is `date`.

Anyone?

Comment: Looks like you have spaces in your date. Remove them.

Comment: strtotime can handle a surprising number of formats. If you pass it a string it doesn't recognize, then that format would not be one of them. just get rid of the spaces and you should be ok

Comment: Guess the issue I was having (when I tried doing exactly what you suggest) was that I was using `replace()` - which didn't work. How would I remove spaces in serialized data?

Comment: What does `echo $this->input->post('pur_date');` show?

Comment: I actually had a misspelling in my `post`. Should have been `pur-date` instead of `pur_date`. However, I'm still not getting the correct date. Echo is this: `2014+/+02+/+31`

Comment: Sorry, it's returning: `2014 / 02 / 31`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, figured it out - thanks to the comments on my initial question. I was able to remove the white space from my string in my model. Post data was `2014 / 02 / 31`, not `2014+/+02+/+31` as was displayed in browser console.

New code:

```
$format = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $this->input->post('pur-date')); // formats string and removes whitespace
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($format));
```

Comment: Bear in mind that February 31st doesn't exist as @logicalicy mentioned in his answer.  PHP treats it as March 3rd. `strtotime('2014/02/31') === strtotime('2014/03/03');`

Comment: I know. Was just an example - and the date would write to db anyways. I have a date selector plug-in which will handle this. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on because the test data (from the form) is not provided but here are some things I would immediately check for:

- Javascript counts in milliseconds, Java counts in seconds, PHP counts in seconds: this is your most likely problem.
- I don't know where 2014-02-31 is coming from. There was no February 31st this year or, for that matter, ever. This could potentially break things?